# How to search with single search condition for all required columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, search, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a table/view having multiple columns in SQL Server. I want to search all rows with a single condition for all columns whereas number of columns are 25 e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE  (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3,........COL_25) > 2
```

Please help!

Comment: are values of columns limited or not?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think exactly what you want is possible but if you add more information we might be able to get you something a little better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check each column individually.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE  COL_1 > 2 AND COL_2 > 2 AND COL_3 > 2 ........AND COL_25 > 2
```

Comment: But it gives values for example `0` but i need just `2` or greater than `2`

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant to put a 2 there.

Comment: What mean to put a 2 there?

Comment: I mean I had a `0` in my example but I should have written a `2`. I fixed it so now it's a `2`.

Comment: If the AND is not working for you, and from your comment, and since the question is unclear, I am guessing : you probably need an OR.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't imagine why, let's assume that you really want only one single condition (without ANDs or CASEs) in the WHERE clause.

You can do that like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 0 = CHARINDEX
(
  '-',
  CAST(COL_1 - 3 AS nvarchar)
+ CAST(COL_2 - 3 AS nvarchar)
+ CAST(COL_3 - 3 AS nvarchar)
-- etc ...
)
```